# Use .htaccess to change where a domain points

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file that changes my .com domain to .co.uk, my .co.uk has a ssl certificate but .com dose not.

When I type:
http:// OR 
www. OR 
example.com

all work fine, but if its http://example.com it does not rewrite to https://www.example.co.uk

How would I change this so it does in .htaccess?

My current rules are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

Many thanks

Comment: what are your current rules?

Comment: Just added them, sorry should have put them their in the first place

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with your rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

needs to be at the very end, otherwise you'll redirect *and* route at the same time.

Then change:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```